# Copy some files and a whole folder from host into container using a unique COPY statement in a Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm running a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) with two COPY statements as such:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt entrypoint.sh ./
COPY binaries/ ./binaries
```

It works fine, I end up having what I need:

```
root:/# ls /app
requirements.txt
entrypoint.sh
binaries/
├── executable1
├── executable2
└── executable3
```

But I'd like to keep the number of layers as low as possible, hence I try to combine the two COPY statements into one:

```
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt entrypoint.sh binaries/ ./
```

But this is 'extracting' all the files from the `binaries/` folder and lay them next to the 2 others:

```
root:/# ls /app
requirements.txt
entrypoint.sh
executable1
executable2
executable3
```

#### Question

How do you combine *both* some files *and* one (or more) specific folder(s) into one unique COPY statement in a Dockerfile (if it's possible of course)?

Environment information:

```
Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3    
Host: ubuntu 18.04.5
```

#### Testing MWE

From `localhost:~$`

```
mkdir -p doc && cd doc && mkdir -p binaries && touch entrypoint.sh \
requirements.txt binaries/ex1 binaries/ex2 binaries/ex3 \
&& echo 'FROM debian:buster-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt entrypoint.sh binaries ./' >> Dockerfile
```

From `localhost:~$`

```
docker build --no-cache -t test:latest . \
&& docker run -it --rm --name test test:latest bash
```

From inside container:

```
root:/app# ls
```

gives me:

```
entrypoint.sh  ex1  ex2  ex3  requirements.txt
```

The same behaviour is encountered when using `ADD` instead of `COPY`.

Comment: remove the `/` at the end of `binaries`: `COPY requirements.txt entrypoint.sh binaries ./`

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to work either. Unfortunately. I've added a MWE showing that.

Comment: have you tried using `ADD` instead?

Comment: Sure, it has the same behaviour, which is not surprising to me as `ADD` is especially build for expanding archive files or URLs. [In > 90% of the case you prefer using COPY](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-2-the-difference-between-copy-and-add-in-a-dockerile).

Comment: If you need more control wrt. layering, there is always the route of using [bazel](https://bazel.build/v) with [`rules_docker`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a *folder* with the following structure alongside your Dockerfile, and *then* copy the contents into your apps directory,

```
$ tree
.
├── Dockerfile
└── folder
    ├── binaries
    │   ├── executable1
    │   ├── executable2
    │   └── executable3
    ├── entrypoint.sh
    └── requirements.txt

2 directories, 6 files
```

Dockerfile,

```
FROM debian:buster-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY folder .
```

---

```
root@b111e73a17c1:/app# tree
.
|-- binaries
|   |-- executable1
|   |-- executable2
|   `-- executable3
|-- entrypoint.sh
`-- requirements.txt

1 directory, 5 files
```

Comment: Little note: as soon as you `WORKDIR /app` all subsequent instructions act as if you `cd`'ed in that folder. So `COPY folder .` could also do (and is shorter to lazy me ;))

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to `COPY` or `ADD` a directory without specifying a destination directory, as pointed by the documentation:

> - If `<src>` is a directory, the entire contents of the directory are copied, including filesystem metadata.
>
> **Note**
>
> The directory itself is not copied, just its contents.

<sup>*Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add & https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy*</sup>

But there are two possibilities here, since docker won't go recursively in your folder you could change your files structure on the host and do something like:

```
.
└── to_mount
    ├── binaries
    │   ├── executable1
    │   ├── executable2
    │   └── executable3
    ├── entrypoint.sh
    └── requirements.txt
```

And then simply:

```sh
COPY to_mount .
```

---

Another way that you could use, which is always nice to know of but which can prove highly unpractical based on your use case is using a [*.dockerignore*](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file.

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named `.dockerignore` in the root directory of the context. If this file exists, the CLI modifies the context to exclude files and directories that match patterns in it. This helps to avoid unnecessarily sending large or sensitive files and directories to the daemon and potentially adding them to images using `ADD` or `COPY`.

*<sup>Source: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file</sup>*

With this you could COPY `.` and then add in the *.dockerignore* the other files that are in your current host folder but that you don't want to copy in the image.

Here is my docker folder

```
.
├── .dockerignore
├── Dockerfile
├── binaries
│   ├── executable1
│   ├── executable2
│   └── executable3
├── docker-compose.yml
├── entrypoint.sh
└── requirements.txt
```

*.dockerignore* contains

```
Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
.dockerignore
```

So, doing:

```
COPY . .
```

I end up with

```
.
├── binaries
│   ├── executable1
│   ├── executable2
│   └── executable3
├── entrypoint.sh
└── requirements.txt
```

---

With the *Dockerfile*

```
FROM alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache tree
WORKDIR /tmp
COPY . .
```

We get

```
$ tree -a
.
├── .dockerignore
├── Dockerfile
├── binaries
│   ├── executable1
│   ├── executable2
│   └── executable3
├── docker-compose.yml
├── entrypoint.sh
└── requirements.txt

1 directory, 8 files

$ docker run --rm -ti $(docker build -q .) tree -a
.
├── binaries
│   ├── executable1
│   ├── executable2
│   └── executable3
├── entrypoint.sh
└── requirements.txt

1 directory, 5 files
```